# Unknown resource referenced in variable with Terraform

Tags: terraform

I am a beginner to Terraform. 
I am trying to execute following code from Terraform Getting started guide.

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "${var.access_key}"
  secret_key = "${var.secret_key}"
  region     = "${var.region}"
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "${lookup(var.amis, var.region)}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags {
    Name = "newprovisionerstest"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo ${aws_instance.example.public_ip} > ip_address.txt"
  }
}

output "ip" {
  value = "${aws_eip.ip.public_ip}"
}
```

When I run

> terraform apply

or

> terraform refresh

It gives following error:

> Error: output 'ip': unknown resource 'aws_eip.ip' referenced in variable aws_eip.ip.public_ip

Why is it so? Is it because "aws_eip" resource is not declared anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like you said it yourself, there is no aws_eip resource called ip. 
If you use the

> aws_instance.example.public_ip

it should work totally fine